# How to get correct output for Pig Latin translator using JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse

I am coding a JAVA application that translates english to pig latin. My application runs with no actual errors but the output is automatic and incorrect. This application will continue to run if the user selects "y".

Can you all see where my error lies?

Thank you.

CODE:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PigLatin2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 // create a Scanner object
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Run through the loop of calculations while user choice is equal to "y" or "Y"
    String choice = "y";

    while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
        // get the input from the user
        System.out.println("Enter a line to be translated");

        System.out.println();

        //Get String entered
        String userInput = sc.toString();
        //Line break
        System.out.println();

        String[] words = userInput.split(" ");

        String output = "";

        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            String pigLatin = translated(words[i]);
            output += pigLatin + " ";
        }

        System.out.println(output);

        //Scan next line
        sc.nextLine();

        //line break
        System.out.println();

        // Ask use they want to continue
        System.out.print("Continue? (y/n): ");

        //Users choice
        choice = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println();
    }//END WHILE LOOP

    //Close scanner object
    sc.close();

}//END MAIN METHOD

private static String translated(String words) {
    String lowerCase = words.toLowerCase();
    int firstVowel = -1;
    char ch;

    // This for loop finds the index of the first vowel in the word
    for (int i = 0; i < lowerCase.length(); i++) {
        ch = lowerCase.charAt(i);

        if (startsWithVowel(ch)) {
            firstVowel = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (firstVowel == 0) {
        return lowerCase + "way";
    }else {
         String one = lowerCase.substring(firstVowel);
         String two = lowerCase.substring(0, firstVowel);
         return one + two + "ay";
    }
}

    public static Boolean startsWithVowel(char ch) {
        if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' || ch == 'y') {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

This is the output I get automatically:

ava.util.scanner[delimiters=\p{javawhitespace}+][position=0][matchjay alid=false][needvay input=false][sourceway osed=false][skipped=false][groupclay eparator=\,][decimalsay eparator=.][positivesay efix=][negativepray efix=\q-\e][positivepray uffix=][negativesay uffix=][nansay ing=\qnan\e][infinitystray ing=\q?\e]stray

Comment: what do you think `String userInput = sc.toString();` does?

Comment: Takes the user input and puts it into the words array?

Comment: Maybe you are confusing it with `choice = sc.nextLine();`

Comment: @Scary Wombat, I figured it out haha it should be:  
            String userInput = sc.nextLine();